# How can I call a stored procedure using Groovy?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, groovy

1. How can I call a stored procedure using Groovy?
2. How can I create a stored procedure from Grails project (as domain classes to create data base)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of calling a FullName stored procedure which takes a param ('Sam' in the example) and returns a VARCHAR.

```
sql.call("{? = call FullName(?)}", [Sql.VARCHAR, 'Sam']) { name ->
    assert name == 'Sam Pullara'
}
```

The same example again but with a GString variation:

```
def first = 'Sam'
sql.call("{$Sql.VARCHAR = call FullName($first)}") { name ->
    assert name == 'Sam Pullara'
}
```

Here is an example of a stored procedure with an out parameter:

```
sql.call '{call Hemisphere(?, ?, ?)}', ['Guillaume', 'Laforge', Sql.VARCHAR], { dwells ->
    println dwells // => Northern Hemisphere
}
```

Refer [this](http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html#_stored_procedures).

Comment: i try these methods but i still have an error:                           No signature of method: static groovy.sql.Sql.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList, vltrafficmonitor.CDRController$_closure3_closure4) values: [{call call endpoint_stats_get(?, ?, ?, ?)}, [1, Mon Dec 20 09:44:00 EET 2010, Mon Dec 20 09:44:00 EET 2010, Sql.%ROWTYPE], vltrafficmonitor.CDRController$_closure3_closure4@8cb09b6]

Comment: Possible solutions: call(java.lang.String), call(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.String, java.util.List), call(java.lang.String, java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), call(groovy.lang.GString), call(groovy.lang.GString, groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: I suggest you add a .toString() to the GStrings, as sql.call does not accept GStrings